# Why do we have to check that the fuel x feed is properly functioning before departing for an ETOPS flight on the A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, etops

In the A320 family series FCOM under the special operations procedure chapter it is mentioned that we have to check the fuel x feed on ground before departing.

Any specific reason why we only check it before departing for ETOPS flights?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The main reason to check the Fuel-X-FEED on the ground before the flight is to allow the pilots to use the total fuel quantity on both wings in case of a single-engine failure during flying in ETOPS.
  (**Due to engine-out scenario you may not be able to feed one engine by both fuel tanks without the FUEL-X-FEED Valve)**
- in addition to this, the Fuel-X-FEED in the A320 MEL is a NO DISPATCH item by means you can't depart without and that reason tracks back to the **EASA** Requirments listed in **[AMC-20 AMENDMENT  - 7](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Annex%20II%20-%20AMC%2020-6.pdf) (APPENDIX 4 - FLIGHT PREPARATION AND IN-FLIGHT PROCEDURES):**

  > **(11)  Fuel  system**
  >
  > (i)    The aeroplane fuel system should provide fuel pressure and flow to the engine(s) in accordance  with  CS  25.951  and  25.955  for  any  fuel  pump  power  supply  failure  condition not shown to be extremely improbable.
  >
  > (ii)   The fuel necessary to complete the ETOPS mission or during a diversion should be available  to  the  operating  engine(s)  under  any  failure  condition,  other  then  fuel  boost pump failures, not shown to be extremely improbable2 (e.g. crossfeed valve failures, automatic fuel management system failures).

Comment: @Islan Almaghraby if that's the case shouldn't be checking it before every flight ? Do you have any information or official reference which explains the reason specifically for ETOPS?

Comment: @Jai - On a long overwater flight you will have a greater need for crossfeed capability if you lose an engine and still need to travel a long distance than if you are overland with multiple divert options. So it's not a bad idea to check every time, but I could understand not requiring it.
P.S.  I notice that you use the term "we" as if you work on or fly these aircraft. Wouldn’t it make sense to ask the people you work with rather than polling random people here?

Comment: @Micheal Hall appreciate your input I didnt mean any offence. I am a professional pilot and I do fly the A320 for a living. Alot of the questions I post on this forum the answers aren't available on the internet. It does make sense to ask my airline especially my engineering department and I do ask them as and when time permits me a number of questions have been answered by them but alot still haven't as I cant always ask them due to circumstances at hand.

Comment: @Islam Elsayed I checked the document which you listed but couldn't find a definitive answer for it.

Comment: @Jai You may find it on page 14, paragraph 11.

Comment: @IslamElsayed I added the text from the document rather than an image. We prefer that since it's searchable like this.

Comment: Thanks, @Bianfable appreciate your input always!

Comment: @Jai since this seems to be pretty conclusive information, do you want to give it a check-mark so others will know that it's been satisfactorily answered? If not, you may want to clarify what point(s) you're still questioning.

Comment: @FreeMan done 